# How do I install this github package via Git Bash (amazon-crawler)

Tags: python, git, github, pip, git-bash

I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/hartleybrody/public-amazon-crawler) github package to work. I have python 3.9, pip 20.2.3 and git 2.28.0.windows.1 installed(all the newest version).
When I try to download the package with the following code in git bash, it gives out an error.

Command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hartleybrody/public-amazon-crawler.git
```

Error:

```
Collecting git+https://github.com/hartleybrody/public-amazon-crawler.git
  Cloning https://github.com/hartleybrody/public-amazon-crawler.git to c:\users\chris\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-ji37p4r1
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-ji37p4r1\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-ji37p4r1\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-pvkyer2s'
         cwd: C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-ji37p4r1\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-ji37p4r1\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also tried just downloading the .zip and unpacking it manually, but there I fail when trying to install the dependencies in the requirements.txt.

Command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Error:

```
Collecting BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz (31 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kt7dwwof\\beautifulsoup\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Chris\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kt7dwwof\\beautifulsoup\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-s9pbmuar'
         cwd: C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kt7dwwof\beautifulsoup\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kt7dwwof\beautifulsoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Unit tests have failed!")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

My question now is: "How do I get it to work?". Is the crawler simply broken, or outdated, or do I need to use something other than git bash, or is it a simple oversight by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st error — the repository doesn't have `setup.py` so it's not `pip`-installable.

2nd error — the `requirements.txt` lists `BeautifulSoup` instead of `BeautifulSoup4` so it's Python2-only.